# The image current due to moving charges and a current carrying thin wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics, induction

Suppose we have a plane conductor and a stream of positively charged particles of mass m moving parallel to the plane conductor at a distance $d$. The trajectory can be assumed to be straight. An image current will be induced in the plane conductor, right?

1. Will the image current depend on the distance $d$? If the
   charged particles are flying much farther away, will the induced current on the plate be the same?
2. Instead of moving charged particles, if I place a current carrying
   thin wire (let us assume a straight wire), will the image current be the same? I am confused here because in the current carrying wire the total charge is zero, so the total image charge should also be zero.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the method of electrostatic images : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges

If so then a charged particle over a perfect conductor can be simplified for calculations

If the particle has a charge $+q$ and is at a distance $d$ from the surface of the perfect conductive plane then the image charge will be at a distance of $-d$ for the perfect conductor and its charge will be $-q$

1. So yes it depends on the distance $d$, if the charged particle goes farther away from the conductive plane its image will also go away from it
2. The image charge of a thin wire will be a charged thin wire as seen through a mirror across the conductive interface.

If the charge of your wire is $q=0$ then it's current is also $I = 0$ as:

$$I = \frac{dQ}{dt}$$

In that case, the image has also $Q' = 0$

Comment: A wire can have a current also if its net charge is zero. For example you can maintain the density of electrons constant, while having them moving along the wire (non zero current density).

Comment: Ok, i'm not sure what happens if you apply the image method in that case

Comment: Yes, as the charge moves away from the conductor, the image will also move away. But, I don't understand how it affect the image current. For example, if the charged particle Q+ is moving parallel to the plate at a distance d1 and another charged particle Q'+ moving at a distance d2. Both has the same positive charge. The rate of change of charge induced on the plate (that is induced current) is same for the both the charged particle moving at d1 and d2 right? So if someone connect an ammeter to the, it will record the same induced current on the conducting plate for both Q+ and Q'+, isn't it?

Comment: @AnthonyLethuillier I think you would need to assume a perfect conductor so the magnetic field does not penetrate it.